# When two definite integrals can be multiplied to get iterated integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

When we can write the following equality:
$$\left(\int_0^a f(x) \, dx\right)\left(\int_0^a g(x) \, dx\right) = \int_0^a \int_0^a f(x)g(y) \, dx \, dy \text{ ?}$$

Is it always true or only in some particular cases?

Comment: All the time !!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_a^b \left( \int_c^d f(x) \underbrace{{}\ g(y)\  {}}\,dx\right)\,dy
$$

In the inside integral as $x$ goes from $c$ to $d$ then $g(y)$ does not change.  It is for that reason that we can rewrite the inside integral as
$$
g(y)\int_c^d f(x)\, dx.
$$
Then we have
$$
\int_a^b\left( g(y) \underbrace{\int_c^d f(x)\, dx}\right)\,dy
$$

And then, as $y$ goes from $a$ to $b$, the expression over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ does not change.  For that reason, it can also be pulled out, getting
$$
\int_a^b g(y)\,dy \cdot \int_c^d f(x)\,dx.
$$

A similar thing applies to sums.